# Issue In Bootstrap Modal

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal, yii2-advanced-app

i am using bootstrap modal for Login. This is my controller code

```
public function actionSignin()
        {
            $this->layout= "main";
            $model = new LoginForm();

            if ( isset( $_POST[ 'LoginForm' ] ) )
            {

                if ( $model->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) && $model->login() )
                {
                    $session = Yii::$app->session;
                    $session['username'] = $model->user->first_name;
                    $session['userid'] = $model->user->id;

                    return $this->redirect( [ '/site/home' ] );
                }
                else
                { 

                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Incorrect Email or Password or both');
                    return  $this->renderAjax( 'signin', [ 'model' => $model ] );
                }
            } 

            else
            {
                return  $this->renderAjax( 'signin', [ 'model' => $model ] );
            }
        }
```

when users click on the following link login form pop's up

```
echo Html::a( Yii::t( 'app', ' {modelClass}', ['modelClass' => 'SignIn',
                        ] ), [ 'account/signin' ], [ 'class' => 'btn btn-link  fa fa-sign-in btn-primary sign']
                        );
```

when user enter the correct username and password user gets redirected to site/home as given in code. But when user enters incorrect username or password the modal should again popup but it is not. Instead i get a page with white background(no layout) with the fields to enter username and password. I am not able to see it in the modal popup why so?

[image: login form with modal popup]

[image: login form when user enters incorrect details]

Comment: Go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927579/how-can-i-show-the-default-login-page-as-modal-popup-in-yii2/25641678#25641678). This might help!

Answer (score 0):

add in your `_form` like:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true,]); ?>
```

Add this code in your `controller` file:

```
public function actionSignin()
{
        $this->layout= "main";
        $model = new LoginForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
           Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
           return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

        if ( $model->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) && $model->login() )
        {
             $session = Yii::$app->session;
             $session['username'] = $model->user->first_name;
             $session['userid'] = $model->user->id;

             return $this->redirect( [ '/site/home' ] );
        }
        else
        { 
             Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Incorrect Email or Password or both');
             return  $this->renderAjax( 'signin', [ 'model' => $model ] );
        }
        return  $this->renderAjax( 'signin', [ 'model' => $model ] );
}
```